# How do I filter items in a list and not break my other filters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a collection of events that I display using the following table

```
<table>
 <tr><th>Title</th><th>Status</th><th><a href="" ng-click="sortField ='StartDateTime'; reverse = !reverse">Start Date</a></th></tr>

 <tr ng-repeat="eachEvent in Events  | filter:query | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
     <td><span>{{eachEvent.Title}}</span></td>
     <td><span>{{eachEvent.Status}}</span></td>
     <td><span>{{eachEvent.StartDateTime|date:'fullDate'}}</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

It works nicely for me, I am able to change the sort order by clicking on the header start date. My question is as follows. I would like to make a select like below:

```
 <select class="form-control">
     <option selected="selected">Any</option>
     <option>InProgress</option>
     <option>Completed</option>
     <option>Canceled</option>
 </select>
```

I would like to filter the items in the table using the selected option. I think I can make a filter that would handle this but I am not sure how to use my filter in the ng-repeat and not mess up my other filters.

Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can chain your filters:

```
<tr ng-repeat="eachEvent in Events | filter: {Status: status} | filter:query | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
    <td><span>{{eachEvent.Title}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{eachEvent.Status}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{eachEvent.StartDateTime|date:'fullDate'}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Or you can combine your filter into one using `$` to match anything:

```
<tr ng-repeat="eachEvent in Events | filter: {$: query, Status: status} | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
    <td><span>{{eachEvent.Title}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{eachEvent.Status}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{eachEvent.StartDateTime|date:'fullDate'}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Or you can create a custom function that determines what is filtered and pass that to the filter

These all assume the following select has `ngModel` of "status" and you are filtering by a property called `Status` and the "Any" option has a blank value.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="status">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Any</option>
    <option>InProgress</option>
    <option>Completed</option>
    <option>Canceled</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this guy had a good solution too http://plnkr.co/edit/lNJNYagMC2rszbSOF95k?p=preview